# Getting Id of theChat Messages

Tags: applescript

I am having trouble getting the Id of a text message chat through the use of Applescripts.

Here is my code so far:

```
using terms from application "Messages"

    on message sent theMessage for theChat
        display dialog (get id of theChat)
    end message sent

end using terms from
```

When I use the Applescript Handler, I get an error:

```
Can’t get id of «class ictt» id "iMessage;-;+1xxxxxxxxxx". (-1728)
```

(x's in place of a phone number)

How do I avoid this error and get the desired output of just `iMessage;-;+1xxxxxxxxxx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what triggers this error, but I have found a reliable work around. I put the statement in a try block, and parse the id from the error message.

```
on splitText(sourceText, textDelimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {textDelimiter}
    set messageParts to (every text item in sourceText) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return messageParts
end splitText

try
    set myresult to get id of theChat
on error errMsg
    set errMsgParts to splitText(errMsg, "\"")
    set errCount to count of errMsgParts
    set myresult to item (errCount - 1) of errMsgParts
end try
```

This works by parsing the text to take only the id from in between the quotes. The split text function was taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateText.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH33-SW6).